# Spread Operator - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, rest, spread

I'm trying to pass an array as an argument with Spread operator but something is going wrong.

```
function addThreeNumbers(x:number, y:number, z:number){
  console.log(x+y+z)
}

const args: number[] = [2,6,4]

addThreeNumbers(...args)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's unclear from the error? You're trying to call a function that needs exactly three parameters by spreading an array that could have any length, and it suggests two possible solutions to that (change the function signature, or the type of args).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For TypeScript to correctly predict what argument types are going to spread into the parameter, you will have to change the `args` variable type into a tuple as follows:

```
const args: [number, number, number] = [2, 6, 4];
```

Comment: That's not correct syntax for defining a type.

Answer (score 4):

It's exactly as the error says:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

So either make `args` a tuple, such as with `as const` so it doesn't get widened to `number[]`:

```
const args = [2, 6, 4] as const;
```

Or make the parameters a rest parameter instead:

```
function addThreeNumbers(...args: number[]) {
    console.log(args[0] + args[1] + args[2])
    // or args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be a number array `number[]` designed to be more generic, capable of accepting any number of arguments.

```
const add = (...numbers: number[]) => {
  return numbers.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value);
};

const addedNumbers = add(5, 10, 2, 3.5);
```